# IPhone location: using near wifi Access Points

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to locate an iphone precisely when I am on a subway. In this case, using aGPS will not give me a reasonably accurate location. Instead, if I use near wifi access points, I would have better information. This [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) explains how to use iPhone's core location API, but does not talk about how the location is retrieved. Is it going to be reliable enough to be used in a subway?

Comment: Can you just go to the subway, pull up a map, and see how good its location is? I would think it’s only going to work if there are a lot of wi-fi access points in the subway.

Comment: that's what I assume too. I am not close to any metro at the moment to check it myself.